# How to show Discounted Price along with strike Discount Amount in Order Summary of checkout after apply the voucher code?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6

I want to show the Items price striked with discounted price after applying voucher code.

[image]

```
app/code/Vendorr/DiscountShower/etc/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd'>
    <type name='Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider'>
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="RltSquare\DiscountShower\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/DiscountShower/Plugin/ConfigProviderPlugin

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin
```

{

```
/**
 *@var checkoutSession
 */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 *Constructor
 * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
 */
public function __construct(CheckoutSession $checkoutSession)
{
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
{
    $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
    foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
        $quoteItem = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($item['item_id']);
        if ($quoteItem->getDiscountPercent()){
            $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['row_total_with_discount'] = $quoteItem->getPrice() - ($quoteItem->getDiscountPercent()/ 100 * $quoteItem->getPrice());
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

}

> app/code/vendor/DiscountShower/view/frontend/web/js/checkout/summary/items/details/subtotal.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total'
],
function (viewModel) {
    "use strict";
    return viewModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            displayArea: 'after_details',
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal.html'
        },
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return this.getFormattedPrice(quoteItem['discount_amount']);
        }
    });
}
```

);

> app/code/Vendor/DiscountShower/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal': 'Vendor_DiscountShower/js/checkout/summary/items/details/subtotal'
    }
}};
```

What is I am doing wrong?